# Best fit prometheus metric data model for grafana sysdig

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, metrics, sysdig

I am using prometheues metric in grafana UI emitted from sysdig dashboard.

I am implementing a state change metric i.e pod states and my data mode is below:

pod_request_state_duration(id,method="create",demoapi,state=creating-running)

I want to use promQL to find the changing state and display in grafana UI. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

As the query is not exact, i will try to give a best possible solution.

Try using [delta](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#delta).

```
delta(pod_request_state_duration{id,method="create",demoapi,state=creating-running}[time_duration])
```

Comment: Thanks @rohatgisanat for the help. I was looking for something similar.

Comment: Cool. Hope it helped.